# Select only one plan at the time React State Hook

Tags: reactjs, indexing, react-hooks, state

So basically I got 3 plans, but I want to be able to only select 1 at the time. But when I do click on 1 all 3 are selected. I output the plans from map, tried using index of each plan, but didn't work.

```
const [selectedPlan, setSelectedPlan] = useState(false);

const handleSelectPlan = () => {
setSelectedPlan((prevSelectedPlan) => !prevSelectedPlan);
};
```

`

```
{data.plans.map((each) => (
      <div className={styles.pricingPlans__each} key={each.id}>
        <div className={styles.header}>
          <h3>{each.header}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.price}>
          <h4>£{each.price}/mo.</h4>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.body}>{each.body}</div>

        <div className={styles.cta}>
          <button onClick={() => handleSelectPlan(each.id)}>
            {selectedPlan ? <FaCheck /> : null} Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
```

Comment: You need an array of Booleans, one for each plan, and then toggle the state of the plan you selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the correct selected plan not just if one is selected:

```
{data.plans.map((each) => (
      <div className={styles.pricingPlans__each} key={each.id}>
        <div className={styles.header}>
          <h3>{each.header}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.price}>
          <h4>£{each.price}/mo.</h4>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.body}>{each.body}</div>

        <div className={styles.cta}>
          <button onClick={() => handleSelectPlan(each.id)}>
            {selectedPlan === each.id ? <FaCheck /> : null} Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
```

selectedPlan ?: will only check for any plan, since a strings is truthy and will result in Facheck to be rendered for all.